# Unexpected fundamental hum in audio demonstration

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft, web-audio-api

I am trying to create a spectral audio demonstration using the web audio API's periodicWave generator. Which can be seen here:
http://orazdow.github.io/bars/

Whenever I have a fair amount of partials turned on the sound is dominated by a loud buzzy hum at the fundamental.

I wasn't expecting this and would like to understand the cause. I was hoping to generate something similar to Pure Data's fourier resynthesis example, which can be seen [here](http://pd-tutorial.com/english/ch03s08.html) at section 3.8.2, but with pure tones rather than filtered noise. I am only writing values to the real part array.

The dominating tone was not what I expected or wanted, so I am hoping to understand what is causing it.

Comment: I think because the beat frequency between any two oscillators is the fundamental frequency, that tone is coming through as beating, and perhaps from constructive interference it's turning into a nasty pulse shape...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the oscillators are doing what's intended.  If you have a flat spectrum (which is what you have in your demo by default except it's band-limited), the signal should be approximately a pulse train (periodic signal of impulses).

I think if you create such a periodic sequence of impulses and listen, it will sound like the oscillators.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I had another demo that used an osc bank which was spaced logarithmically which probably mislead me, but this makes sense in terms of understanding the fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on many partials, you may have to reduce the volume of all of them to prevent clipping the peaks (exceeding the maximum range).

Comment: createPeriodicWave creates a signal with a max amplitude of 1 (usually), so it shouldn't clip.  At least not by very much.